# How to setup SVN over VPN?

Tags: centos, vpn, subversion

I'm looking on how to implement a SVN connection over a VPN on my CentOs server.

I need to see up this VPN to work with the team in the office from outside.

1. required packages ( yum ... )
2. configuration files I have to mod ( /etc/... )
3. a basic configuration example

I don't have any particular requirement I just need to set up this service in order to get it work. ( so any suggested kind of VPN that can suit this is accepted ).

Comment: just use system packager to install the vpn and svn packages. There should be no "extra" configuration compared to setting up either of those packages separately.

Comment: sorry, you are right on this ... I just update the question t

Comment: Errm, what's wrong with running svn over https? That's encrypted, and generally less work to set up. Other than that, though, you'll need to tell us what type of VPN you want to run—there are dozens...

Comment: I suggest joining http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux and hashing out the requirements, unless you already know them all. Seems like something that's going to take a fair bit of discussion

Comment: I have edited the question in order to make it less generic ... please, let me know how can i make it more precise in order to get a costrutive answer

Comment: Do they already have a VPN server set up, or are you setting up both sides of the connection? And why the requirement for VPN, instead of just using https? Further, do you really need a VPN; would ssh connection tunneling be enough?

Comment: Which VPN do you want to use, or more specifically what devices are you targeting for the VPN. Hint: iOS/Android/Windows device, you want ipsec. Linux to Linux/OSX/Win, maybe OpenVPN is better.

Comment: @Tim Android has OpenVPN. Prior to 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) you needed to be rooted or running Cyanogen. [4.0+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.blinkt.openvpn&feature=search_result) *or* [Pre-4.0](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schaeuffelhut.android.openvpn.installer&feature=search_result) [and this too](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schaeuffelhut.android.openvpn&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiZGUuc2NoYWV1ZmZlbGh1dC5hbmRyb2lkLm9wZW52cG4iXQ..)

Comment: we are evaluating witch method to use: https/VPN.
The client will be a normal linux client ( I'm using ubuntu )
The problem is that at the moment we don't have a firewall and for this reason we don't have any outside connection open.

Comment: @Francesco you'd have to open it for the VPN anyway.

Comment: @Francesco if you don't have a firewall, then nothing is stopping connections to the server. Most likely you do have a firewall, its just some cheap router (Linksys, DLink, Netgear, etc.). But all of those actually support port forwarding.

Comment: Sorry It is not a problem of routing ... I mean we have no technical issue in open any connection it is just for security reason we have blocked outside connection.
@peteph: for sure, I cannot commit by mail :P
So we need a safety way to open this connection ( in future we will have a firewall, maybe some bsd distro, and we can use lower security, I guess )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN has no specific setup to use it over VPN.
This is just a generic VPN, possibly with a bit of port forwarding.

From the comments I take your office needs to set up a VPN server if they don't want to open the internal network at all.
SSH tunneling would be another possibility when ssh would be allowed.

If that VPN server is set up, you just install the VPN package with yum and place the config files that should be prepared by the VPN server admin (which might or might not be you).

"not having a firwall" at the office location probably means you have no open/fowared ports on the router.
When internal IPs for the office network are used and internet access is achieved through Network Adress Translation (NAT) you actually have a firewall.
You need to forward the VPN server port.

The VPN then needs access to the SVN server.
So either the SVN server is part of the VPN (or on the same server)
or you need another port forwarding on any VPN machine in the internal network (probably the server) to the SVN server.

You access the SVN server then with an address in the VPN.

Comment: Use SSH tunneling. SSH is probably already running, and this is a lot easier to configure than setting up VPN.